# "File not found" When using command instead of plain text

Tags: macros, includegraphics, addresses, chain

Good Day,

I am trying to find an efficient method to acces files in a remote folder.
I have defined several commands for the paths.

Line 6 of the below code works and includes the correct file, whereas line 8 states "file not found"--
but shouldn't these two paths be exactly the same? Am I not allowed to concatenate commands like this?

```
1 \newcommand{\results}{../../code/data/results/}
2 \newcommand{\synthetic}{\results synthetic/}
3 \newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz.pdf}
4
5
6 \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf}
7
8 \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic \sine{100}}
```

Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious. This is the first time I work with pathnames in commands.
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Cheers

EDIT:
This is a full code example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\results}{../../code/waveletTest/data/results/}
\newcommand{\synthetic}{\results synthetic/}
\newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf}

%\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic \sine{100}}

\end{document}
```

This code shows me the file I want. 
If I comment back in the next-to-last line, I get this error:

```
File `../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf' not found. ...width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic \sine{100}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added real code and an error message.

Comment: oh sorry I misread, try `\newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz}`

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system at some stage of processing your `\includegraphics`-command you get the sequence:
`\filename@parse{\synthetic\sine{100}}`

`\filename@parse` is a routine of the LaTeX 2ε-kernel which shall split its argument into

1. Path to file. The path to the file is to be stored in the macro `\filename@area`.
2. Name of file (without extension). The name of the file (without extension) is to be stored in `\filename@base`.
3. Extension of filename. The extension of the name of the file is to be stored in `\filename@ext`. In  case there is no extension, `\filename@ext` is let equal to `\relax`.

What does happen:

On my system `\filename@parse`, syntax:
`\filename@parse{⟨file-path/filename-specification⟩}`
, is defined as follows:

```
> \filename@parse=macro:
#1->\let \filename@area \@empty \expandafter \filename@path #1/\\
```

So `\filename@parse` initializes `\filename@area` to equal the macro `\empty`—the macro `\empty` just vanishes from the token-stream during its toplevel-expansion, without processing any argument, and with delivering a replacement-text which is empty/which does not consist of any token at all—and calls the routine `\filename@path` after "hitting" the first token of the argument with `\expandafter` **once** and appending `/\\` to the result.  (In case the argument `#1` is empty, the appended slash `/` will be hit by `\expandafter` which isn't harmful as the explicit slash-character-token (of catcode 12(other)) is not expandable.)

The routine `\filename@path` will be explained shortly. At this point only so much: **`\filename@path` is indented to process a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens** that forms a file-path/filename-specification (`#1`), trailed by an explicit slash-character-token `/` of category code 12(other) and a control-symbol-token `\\` as delimiter/marker for the end of the file-path/filename-specification.

Therefore the "hitting with `\expandafter` once" is done by `\filename@parse` in case the argument for providing the file-path/filename-specification does not consist of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens but is formed by a macro-token whose top-level-expansion yields a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens.
**This "hitting with `\expandafter` once" implies that with things like `\includegraphics`, which internally use `\filename@parse`, you can provide file-path/filename-specifications only in terms of token-sequences where hitting the first token of the sequence by `\expandafter` once suffices for obtaining the entire sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens which forms the file-path/filename-specification.**

Be aware that in your scenario a single "hit with `\expandafter`" on the first token of the sequence `\synthetic \sine{100}` does not yield the entire (fully expanded) file-path/filename-specification in terms of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens but yields the sequence `\results synthetic/\sine{100}` where more expansion-work needs to be done.

Therefore splitting/splicing off the components (path to file, name of file without extension, filename-extension) is not done correctly by `\filename@path` and its underlying routines.

The routine `\filename@path` in turn, which "expects" the file-path/filename-specification to be provided in terms of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens, syntax:
`\filename@path ⟨file-path/filename-specification in terms of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens⟩/\\`
; `/` is folder/directory-separator
, is defined as follows:

```
> \filename@path=macro:
#1/#2\\->\ifx \\#2\\\def \reserved@a {\filename@simple #1.\\}\else \edef \filen
ame@area {\filename@area #1/}\def \reserved@a {\filename@path #2\\}\fi \reserve
d@a
```

`\filename@path` is a recursive loop which in each iteration appends the next `/`-delimited segment of the file-path/filename-specification to the macro `\filename@area` until reaching the last such segment which denotes the filename.  That next (and probably last) segment is in `#1`. The segments following that next segment are in `#2`. Thus indicator for the last segment is the emptiness of `#2`.
The test for emptiness of `#2` is:
`\ifx\\#2\\⟨tokens in case #2 is empty⟩\else⟨tokens in case #2 is not empty⟩\fi`
When reaching the last such segment, which denotes the filename, the macro `\filename@simple` is called for checking whether that last segment/filename contains a dot (`.`) and therefore a filename-extension needs to be spliced off from the filename. If a filename-extension needs to be spliced off, this is done by means of the macro `\filename@dot`.

When calling `\filename@simple`, syntax:
`\filename@simple ⟨filename-specification in terms of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens⟩.\\`,
on the last `/`-delimited segment which denotes the filename, the sequence `.\\` is appended to the last segment.
So `\filename@simple` can gather a dot-delimited argument `#1` and a `\\`-delimited argument `#2` and depending on the emptiness of `#2` detect whether a dot present in the segment or the appended dot was taken for the delimiter of the dot-delimited argument.

`\filename@simple` is defined as follows:

```
> \filename@simple=macro:
#1.#2\\->\ifx \\#2\\\let \filename@ext \relax \else \edef \filename@ext {\filen
ame@dot #2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base {#1}
```

If the last segment/filename did not contain a dot, the `.` from the appended sequence `.\\` will be taken for the delimiter of `#1` while the `\\`-delimited `#2` will be empty. Otherwise the first dot of the last segment will be taken for the delimiter of `#1` while the `\\`-delimited `#2` will not be empty. Thus emptiness of `#2` (`\ifx\\#2\\`...) is taken as indicator whether the last segment forms a filename without (dot-separated) extension or forms a filename that is separated from a file-extension by a dot. If `#2` is empty, then `\filename@ext` is "`\let`" equal to `\relax`. Otherwise, while defining `\filename@ext` via `\edef`, `\filename@dot` is applied to the things behind the first dot for removing the appended sequence `.\\`. In any case `\filename@base` is defined to expand to the things before the first dot.

`\filename@dot` is defined as follows:

```
> \filename@dot=macro:
#1.\\->#1
```

This `\filename@parse`-mechanism is nice. But it has some restrictions.

E.g., it is assumed that filenames contain at most one dot.

E.g., it is assumed that with filenames that contain at most one dot, the dot separates the name of the file (without extension) from the filename-extension which in turn is not empty. Filenames ending with a dot (which are perfectly "legal" on some file-systems) might cause trouble.

E.g., special characters with special category-codes are not taken into account. E.g., with file-path/filename-specifications which contain curly braces the curly braces might be unbalanced or may be stripped off and/or may "mask" dots and slashes from being taken for delimiters of delimited arguments. Such things cause trouble. E.g., file-path/filename-specifications which contain hashes might cause problems when it comes to defining temporary macros like `\reserved@a` or the macros that hold the results of splitting the file-path/filename-specification.

E.g., it is assumed that a single "hit" by `\expandafter`/that triggering a single expansion-step (→that's what the term "toplevel-expansion" is about) on the first token of the argument of `\filename@parse` suffices for obtaining the entire file-path/filename-specification in terms of a sequence of non-expandable explicit character-tokens. In your scenario this is not the case and therefore attempts at splitting things takes place while `\sine` is not expanded yet and therefore the dot that separates the filename (without extension) from the filename-extension cannot be "seen" by the `\filename@simple` mechanism yet. Therefore in your scenario the graphicx-package erroneously "assumes" that no filename-extension is specified. In case the graphicx-package "assumes" (be the assumption correct or erroneous) that a filename-extension is not specified, it tries with some default-extensions.

E.g., instead with `../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf` it tries with
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf.pdf`,
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf.png`,
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf.jpg`,
etc.

That's why typing "H*⟨return⟩*" when the error-message pops up on the console/screen yields:

```
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

The suggestion by David Carlisle (who wrote the graphicx-package) of omitting the filename-extension `.pdf` aims at the fact that, although in this case expanding things before checking for the presence of a filename-extension still will not take place in a way which would satisfy puristic minds, the graphicx-package's assumption of no filename-extension being specified will be correct and that therefore the graphicx-package does try the default-extensions in a way which works out—the graphicx-package tries with
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf`,
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.png`,
`../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.jpg`,
etc.
The first one already works out.

All these things can be addressed by loading the package [grffile](https://ctan.org/pkg/grffile):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\results}{../../code/waveletTest/data/results/}
\newcommand{\synthetic}{\results synthetic/}
\newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz.pdf}

%\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic\sine{100}}

\end{document}
```

By the way:

In your very special case you can trick the `\filename@parse`-mechanism into splicing off the filename-extension correctly by adding `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\results}{../../code/waveletTest/data/results/}
\newcommand{\synthetic}{\results synthetic/}
\newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz.pdf}

%\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\expandafter\synthetic\sine{100}}

\end{document}
```

At least on my system this works out.

Be aware that this does splice off the filename-extension correctly **but that this does not separate correctly the file-path from the filename**.
The file-path will be taken for empty.
The sequence `\synthetic sine_100hz` will be taken for the filename.
Seems this does not matter.

But `\filename@parse` is a macro of the LaTeX 2ε-kernel. And there have been a lot of changes and innovations to the LaTeX 2ε-kernel in the recent past. Probably the `\filename@parse` on your system does not work out as it does on my system.

I assume that "hitting the first token of the argument by `\expandafter` once for obtaining from the top-level-expansion of a macro the file-path/file-name-specifications in terms of non-expandable explicit character tokens" will not be removed from `\filename@parse`.
Therefore you can apply some `\romannumeral`-expansion-trickery which needs one hit by `\expandafter` for delivering the file-path/filename-specification:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\results}{../../code/waveletTest/data/results/}
\newcommand{\synthetic}{\results synthetic/}
\newcommand{\sine}[1]{sine_#1hz.pdf}

%\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf}

\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\romannumeral0\expandafter\synthetic\sine{100}}

\end{document}
```

What does happen here?

`\filename@parse`'s `\expandafer` does "hit" `\romannumeral`.
Then `\romannumeral`-triggered gathering of a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity is in progress:

```
%\romannumeral-triggered gathering of a TeX-number-quantity is in progress:
0\expandafter\synthetic\sine{100}
```

Now LaTeX finds the digit `0` and discards it.
Now the process of gathering a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity is turned into the process of gathering more digits or something that terminates gathering the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity:

```
%\romannumeral-triggered gathering of more digits is in progress; digit "0" found.
\expandafter\synthetic\sine{100}
```

Now LaTeX expands `\expandafter`. The result of expanding `\expandafter` is expanding `\sine`:

```
%\romannumeral-triggered gathering of more digits is in progress; digit "0" found.
\synthetic sine_100hz.pdf
```

Now LaTeX expands `\synthetic`.

```
%\romannumeral-triggered gathering of more digits is in progress; digit "0" found.
\results synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf
```

Now LaTeX expands `\results`.

```
%\romannumeral-triggered gathering of more digits is in progress; digit "0" found.
../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf
```

Now LaTeX finds a dot. That dot is not a digit. Unlike a space-token it does not get discarded. Like a space-token it does end `\romannumeral`-triggered gathering of (components of) TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities. Therefore LaTeX only found the digit/number `0` while 0 is not a positive number. With non-positive numbers `\romannumeral` does silently not return any token at all:

```
%\romannumeral done.
../../code/waveletTest/data/results/synthetic/sine_100hz.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for crafting such an elaborate and detailed answer.
All your suggested solutions work on my system.
I am happy that I now understand a lot better what happens during processing of my LaTeX input, and why my first try did not work.
Have a great day!

Comment: @TakuroSpirit I do not know about your level of expertise and experience in dealing with LaTeX. If I am writing things that are already known, I ask for forgiveness. But there is the TeX-primitive `\show` which is very valuable for finding out what is going on: `\show<token>`  in your .tex-input-file yields displaying on screen and in the .log-file the meaning of `<token>`. In case `<token>` is a control-sequence, you can see how it is defined. `\show` ends its message with a dot which does not belong to the meaning but does end the sentence written to screen.

Comment: @TakuroSpirit I wish a great day to you, too. :-)  On the one hand this morning the village where I live suffered the second casualty due to Covid-19-disease. On the other hand when my father and me took a short secluded walk through the countryside in the evening, we saw the first blossoms on the cherry trees. ;-)

Comment: note though that the current version of grffile does nothing at all (just inputs graphics)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The actions of the current version of grffile do not depend on the release of the graphics-package in use?

Comment: no, there is a rollback option (which loads an old grffile) but anyone with an older tex distribution will have an old grffile.sty getting a new grffile in an old system isn't useful.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I have used LaTeX a lot, but never explored it in depth. Therefore I did not know any of this, and your advice is much appreciated. I tried out ```\show``` and like what it does. Though from ```\show\includegraphics``` to ```\filename@parse``` it's probably quite the journey. I wish you and your father all the best. Stay safe!